# Cannot run a .jar file

Tags: java

I'm having issues when I try to execute a .jar file. I always get the message from the command prompt "cannot find or load main class" every time I try to run the file I have just compiled.

I have tried the following(using the command prompt and saving the java code with Notepad++ and creating the manifest.txt file in the same folder where the .java code was saved):

```
javac classname.java

java cfm classname.jar manifest.txt classname.class

java -jar classname
```

I have also tried:

```
javac classname.java

java classname
```

And:

```
java packagename.classname
```

After compiling the .java file

I know there are hundreds of questions like this in the forums, but I have looked everywhere and I keep getting the same error. I just cannot run the .jar file even after I create it.

It's probably something I have missed but I am out of ideas.

Manifest:

Main-Class: classname

Comment: Show us your MANIFEST.

Comment: I assume when you wrote `java cfm classname.jar ...` you meant `jar cfm classname.jar ... `? What package is the class in?

Comment: Yes, I meant "jar" instead of "java", sorry about that. The class is inside the defaut package but renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see.

```
java -jar classname.jar
```

would work if your MANIFEST.MF calls out the correct class.

```
java -cp classname.jar my.package.MyClass
```

would work in any case.